# Machine Learning with Rapidminer on NASA Turbofan Engine Dataset

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, rapidminer

I'm working on NASA dataset Turbofan engine, which includes time series for each engine. All engines are of the same type, but each engine starts with different degrees of initial wear and variations in the manufacturing process, which is unknown to the user. There are three optional settings that can be used to change the performance of each machine. Each engine has 21 sensors collecting different measurements related to the engine state at runtime. I want to apply different ML models and compare them but I don't know what is the label feature for models? because for example for some cycle time it goes until 140 cycle time and then failed and for some cycle, it goes until 50 cycles and failed... and it's in the row not column ( I don't know it would be an issue or not)

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more what you're trying to predict from what?

Answer (score 0):

your question is a bit broad for stackoverflow (people here are in favor of concrete technical solutions).

But anyway, the "trick" with this data set is, as you have already noticed, to create a label on your own. The maximum number of cycles is a good option here.

Take a look at the community repository within RapidMiner, there is a sample process on this data set:

*//Community Samples/Community Real World Use Cases/Predictive Maintenance on Turbofan Engines*

For more specific questions and tips and tricks on using RapidMiner, I also recommend the RapidMiner user community: https://community.rapidminer.com/ which is very active and great place to start a conversation.

Best,
David